# Allow PHP for accessing filesystem

Tags: php, lamp, mint, passwd

I'm a newbie and I have installed Linux Mint (x64 Ubuntu-based) and Apache v2.0, PHP 5.5.9 and MySQL.

Then I installed WordPress and I was almost unable to upload and edit files (I got "Permission denied")

Now I have two questions:

- **How I can allow PHP for accessing filesystem easily?**
- I've tried removing password with `$ sudo passwd -d ehsaan` now password isn't removed, but password has been changed and I can't access `$ sudo`, even I tried my password, but I doesn't accept.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thank you, but how I can restore my password?

Comment: Please see my newly created answer for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`passwd` has nothing to do with (file system) permissions. The former manages authentication data, the latter is a form of authorisation record.

### Rectify web server permissions

Take a look at the ownership and read permissions of the directory subtree of your WordPress installation. They need to be readable by the user the web server runs as.

### Reset deleted (super-)user password

I recommend you consult [*How do I reset a lost administrative password?*](https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/175814) for that.